# Check if directory has already been processed by cmake

Tags: cmake

I need to invoke `get_directory_properties` on a given directory. However the given directory may be a directory that cmake has not processed (yet) in which case aforementioned command returns an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:111 (get_directory_property):
  get_directory_property DIRECTORY argument provided but requested directory
  not found.  This could be because the directory argument was invalid or, it
  is valid but has not been processed yet.
```

Therefore my idea is to verify that the given directory was indeed processed by cmake already (and thus I can safely invoke `get_directory_properties` on it) and if not I want to do something else.
I was however unable to find a way to check for that and I can't seem to find anything on that on the internet so far. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do this easily, for a large project. If your project is small enough, you might find the [`SUBDIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/SUBDIRECTORIES.html) directory property useful, which contains a list of already-processed sub-directories for the given directory. Otherwise, you could create and update a global list of processed directories as CMake configuration runs, then check that list for a given directory as needed.

Comment: @squareskittles The `SUBDIRECTORIES` property is actually the one I want to obtain ^^ But using that on the current dir to see if the respective subdirectory has been processed yet seems like a reasonable workaround. I think it'd break though as soon as the current directory is itself an unprocessed directory (I am planning on processing the directories iteratively)...

Comment: AFAIK there is no easy way at the moment. In general you can start from CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR and traverse all SUBDIRECTORIES to check if your directory in question can be reached from there, but i think you know that already. If i also understood your comment properly then you can limit your search already to CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR and its (recursive) children.